# qt 5.0.2 fullscreen resize

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu

Good day!
I try to make QT fullscreen app that worked on many screen resolutions.
So I developed layout for 1600 * 900 screen and want that on monitors with 1920*1080 my app will be centered. I can center not in fullscreen mode perfectly this peace of code

```
widget->move(QApplication::desktop()->screen()->rect().center() - widget->rect().center());
```

but in fullscreen it doesn't work my platform is Lubuntu 13.10.
Is there any solutions?

Comment: You should check the value of `QApplication::desktop()->screen()->rect().center()`, `widget->rect().center()` and the subtraction to see what's going on - use qDebug()

Comment: widget->move(100,100); doesn't work also

Comment: what is the class of you widget?

Comment: class Widget : public QWidget

Comment: I'm not sure you can move a Widget which is fullscreen. Does move() work when not in FS?

Comment: Then my guess is you can't move a window while it's in FS mode. You've got to find another way to do it. You can try to put your widget on a QWindow, set the window FS and adapt the size of your widget

Comment: Not worked also. widget->move(300,300);
      QLayout* layout= new QHBoxLayout();
      layout->addWidget(widget);
      w->setLayout(layout);

Comment: Ok. Did you try on another platform?